# The reopen vote interface kind of sucks (so what could be done to improve that?)

Tags: feature-request, user-interface

I gauged whether to vote to reopen for this question, https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/posts/93321/revisions, but I realized I couldn't accurately determine if the OP had improved it or not.

I had to open the question itself in a new tab.  The comment back and forth there, as well as the edit history, made me decide to vote to reopen.  But none of that was available on the vote page.  Or I failed to find it, in which case I will still claim that the UI is to blame.

I think more information should be available directly on the vote page.  At least the same quantity of information should be available, if in a different arrangement.  This isn't just a problem for the reopen votes page, but reopen votes usually demand a little more subtlety than close, first post, or low-quality, because the question text doesn't necessarily speak for itself.

Comment: Definitely agree. In the close/reopen queues, I almost always open the question in a new window to get maximum context for a good decision.